# Javascript including 2 strings in a function

Tags: javascript

> Write a function called `stringIncludes`, which accepts two strings: the first string is a word and the second string is a single character. The function should return true if the first string includes the character, otherwise it should return false.  Do not use the built in `String.includes()` function.

This is what I have so far. I know my else statement should be outside of the loop because it's always returning false but nothing seems to be working for me.

```js
function stringIncludes(awesome, e) {
  for (i = 0; i < awesome.length; i++) {
    if (awesome[i] === e) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `else` entirely and put `return false` at the end of your function

Answer (score 1):

> "I know my else statement should be outside of the loop because it's
> always returning false but nothing seems to be working for me"

Well, you already found the solution...

```
function stringIncludes(awesome, e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < awesome.length; i++) {
    if (awesome[i] === e) {
      return true
    }   
  }
  return false; //We searched and haven't found the char
}
```

Please also note that the `i` variable should be declared with `let` or else it's global.

Comment: @Nick without a `let` or `var` (as it is in OP's code), it is indeed global

Comment: @Phil Ahah, I totally missed the omission of a `var` in the original code, just assumed it was yet another `let` recommendation, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use *indexOf()*, you are not prevented from using it